# Capture Key Press screen shot using ADB HTC EVO

Tags: android, debugging, screenshot

I wanted to put together a few screen shots for an app to use in a "walkthrough". I have finally got the Android Debug bridge to work and can bring up the screen capture feature.

What i am wondering is this.

Is it possible to capture a screen press in the screen shot? For example in the picture below you can see the screen option " Home Button Launch " is highlighted, I would like to accomplish this same thing, as I press the buttons, ex : Menu>WallPaper>  and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the sample picture you linked I think that the person is not actually capturing a "screen press" they just used the scroll ball / d pad to navigate to that item in the list (which puts it into "selected" mode which with the default selector item as the background generally makes it look some shade of orange on most(but not all) devices. Then they took the screen shot while that item was selected. To do this you need a device with a scroll ball or d/pad that will let you navigate around the screen like that (the newer tablets don't have this ability that i've found, everything is touchscreen only, If you are using one of these devices you'll have to edit your code a little bit to call .getFocus() for each view you want to be highlighted one at a time.) Then just highlight a view and save the screen shot and repeat for every view you wish to have a screen shot of.

Edit: I am pretty sure the evo doesn't have any sort of scrolling device (track ball or d-pad etc).

> if you spin the mouse wheel, it will cycle through the views (including button views) so you can make it appear as if it were pressed

Doesn't work for me on Moto Xoom, do you do it after you press the screen capture button while the picture is displayed in the window inside of eclipse? This would make this process much quicker and easier if I could get it to work, thanks for the info.

Unless you can get that mouse wheel to work I think the easiest way to do it is override one of the hardware buttons temporarily (back, or volume up/down would work I think) to cycle focus through all of the views in your layout. that way you don't have to call getFocus() one by one and recompile and run it for every different view you want a highlighted pic of. Then just use that button to cycle through the views and save a pic of each.

Comment: I'll look into the Getfocus idea. @jkhouw1 Also a good idea, just alot of work changing images one by one. @omermuhammed  I would prefer a Video, but while that means having to get a video recording program im still left with the same problem. not being able to show them a good walkthrough with out my giant fingers being in the video.

Answer (score 0):

two options:

if you spin the mouse wheel, it will cycle through the views (including button views) so you can make it appear as if it were pressed

Or just temporarily change the image of the button you want to appear as depressed to be your depressed image.